# Prevent MSMQ queues from being removed and recreated during a major upgrade

Tags: wix, wix3

I have an installer which creates MSMQ message queues. During a major upgrade I am noticing that the queues are getting removed and reinstalled. Any suggestions to avoid this from happening?

I am currently scheduling remove existing products after InstallInitialize

```
<RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>
```

Comment: I am now thinking (years later) that it is not appropriate to have message queues get removed on uninstall if you are interested in message durability.

Comment: Major upgrades removing and reinstalling components in an undesirable fashion is a classic MSI problem. Though not entirely the same as your problem, [**this issue is similar, and there are a number of potential workarounds to deal with it**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375540/129130). Perhaps also [**see section 5 here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45840087/129130) (list of common real-world MSI problems).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Component that contains the Message Queue. It is probably getting upgraded which causes the queue to get upgraded.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent a component from getting upgraded?

Comment: Not if you schedule the RemoveExistingProducts that early.

Comment: Rob, can you expand on your comment? Pretend I am completely confused by Windows Installer command sequencing.