# WIX service installer overrides service Installer settings

Tags: c#, wix, windows-services

i am working on a service that is later deployed by a WIX installer.
this is service installer  class

```
this.ServiceInstaller.DisplayName = "My Service";
            this.ServiceInstaller.ServiceName = "MyService";
            this.ServiceInstaller.ServicesDependedOn = new string[] {
        "ServiceA",
        "ServiceB",
        "ServiceC"};
```

and this is the WIX installer code

```
    <Component Id="MyService.exe" Guid="{1234}">
        <File Id="MyService.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$system\$(sys.BUILDARCH)\MyService.exe">
          <netfx:NativeImage Id="MyService.exe" Platform="all" Priority="1" />
        </File>
        <ServiceInstall Id="MyService.exe" DisplayName="My OTHER Service" Name="MyService" ErrorControl="normal" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess">
          <ServiceDependency Id="ServiceD" />
          <ServiceDependency Id="ServiceE" />
          <ServiceDependency Id="ServiceF" />
          <util:ServiceConfig FirstFailureActionType="restart" SecondFailureActionType="restart" ThirdFailureActionType="restart" RestartServiceDelayInSeconds="10" />
        </ServiceInstall>
        <ServiceControl Id="MyService.exe" Name="MyService" Stop="install" Remove="uninstall" />
    </Component>
```

as far as i can tell, the configuration in the WIX completely overrides the settings in the project installer. (specifically name and dependencies)
is this a default behavior?
whats the point of having a serviceInstaller class if WIX is going to completely ignore it?

Comment: service can be also installed using `installutil.exe`

Comment: ***ServiceInstaller classes*** are generally meant to be used **during development** for **testing purposes**. There are many ways to install services, but you should use the MSI tables `ServiceInstall` and `ServiceControl` if you can.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Cross Linking***: A couple of similar answers: **`1)`** [Chris Painter on service credential preservation and / or handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61882958), **`2)`** [Service debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61149858/129130).

---

***ServiceInstaller classes***: This feature is generally meant to be used during **`development`** for **`testing purposes`**. You use the **`InstallUtil.exe`** .NET tool for installation and / or Visual Studio.

---

***Prefer MSI***: There are many ways to install services, but you should use the MSI tables **`ServiceInstall`** and **`ServiceControl`** if you can. Below are some further details on various more or less crazy options.

---

***Service Registration Options***: An old, classic document from **`Phil Wilson`** (**`MSI MVP`** and author of [**`"The Definitive Guide to Windows Installer"`**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592972)) listed a number of ways to install services by means of:

- **`1)`** ***MSI*** - **`ServiceInstall`**, **`ServiceControl`** tables - and a few others.

  - [**`WiX service installation sample 1`**](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/WindowsService)
  - [**`WiX service installation sample 2`**](https://github.com/Robs79/How-to-create-a-Windows-Service-MSI-Installer-Using-WiX)
- **`2)`** ***Win32*** - **`CreateService`** APIs.
- **`3)`** ***Registry*** - manually update, generally an undesirable "under-the-hood" option.
- **`4)`** ***WMI Classes*** - **`Win32_Service`**. Major benefit: [Scriptable](https://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/os/services/). Wraps **`CreateService`** (Win32).
- **`5)`** ***InstallUtil.exe*** - .NET tool & installer classes.
- **`6)`** ***MSI & Installer Class Custom Actions*** - calls **`InstallUtil.exe`** via the shim dll **`InstallUtilLib.Dll`** in Visual Studio Setup Projects - not a favorite option of mine. A lot of complexity for no gain basically. Just use the service tables in the MSI. Automagic.

---

***InstallUtil.exe***: When .NET arrived, a tool called InstallUtil.exe was introduced together with a set of installer classes in the .NET framework.  The ServiceInstaller framework class contains code to install Services, and the developer can override the class methods to provide extra install-time code. This provides a useful way for developers to easily install Services for testing purposes.

---

Many years later one could add to Phil's list:

- [*SC.exe*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/251192/how-to-create-a-windows-service-by-using-sc-exe) - https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html
- [*Regsvcs.exe*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regsvcs-exe-net-services-installation-tool)
- **Powershell** - [*New-Service*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-7), [*Set-Service*](https://ss64.com/ps/set-service.html), etc...

More exotic: Srvany (run app as service, very outdated - don't use).

---

***Essential Service Tools***: There are many essential tools for working with services such as: **`SC.exe`**, **`Services.msc`**, **`NET`**, **`etc...`** [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) is good for more advanced debugging - for example what files your service holds locked that cause upgrade problems, or other problems. There is a list of any further tools here: https://installdude.com/jumpgate.php and click the **`"Debugging"`** label (towards top, under search box) and then click **`"Essential Service Tools"`**.

---

**Windows Services Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ): https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html**

Comment: the WIX installer is used as part of a larger product. its built just around the service.
i'm not looking for alternatives, just to confirm my observation that settings from the serviceInstaller are overwritten.

Comment: I have [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375540) on a slightly different aspect of this (preserve settings on upgrade). Maybe skim it. And at least have a read of the section on ***"managed service account"*** - essentially to run the service with a password-less account so no credentials have to be added to your package. [Service accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/service-accounts).

Comment: [Also see this recent answer from Chris Painter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61882958).